# R - Output a text file from a dataframe with a specific format

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
 Name   Occupation    Country code   Remarks
 Mark   Engineer      1              Ok
 Jerry  Engineer      1              None
 Marie  Veterinarian  2              Ok
 Nolan  Veterinarian  2              Ok
 Max    Shepherd      2              Ok
```

I want to create one text file per country, say:

output1.txt:

```
 Engineer
 Mark - Ok
 Jerry - None
```

output2.txt:

```
 Veterinarian
 Marie - Ok
 Nolan - Ok

 Shepherd
 Max - Ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `split` in. `base R` into a `list` of `vector`s

```
df2 <- transform(df1, NameRemarks = paste(Name, Remarks,
        sep=" - "))[, c("NameRemarks", "Occupation", "Countrycode")]
lst1 <- lapply(split(df2[-3], df2$Countrycode), 
           function(x) split(x['NameRemarks'], x$Occupation))
#$`1`
#$`1`$Engineer
#   NameRemarks
#1    Mark - Ok
#2 Jerry - None


#$`2`
#$`2`$Shepherd
#  NameRemarks
#5    Max - Ok

#$`2`$Veterinarian
#  NameRemarks
#3  Marie - Ok
#4  Nolan - Ok
```

The format may not fit well in writing the file.  One option is `capture.output`

```
Map(capture.output, lst1, file = paste0("output", seq_along(lst1), ".txt"))
```

-output

[image]

For storing purpose, it may be better to do a single `split`

```
lst1 <- split(df2[-3], df2$Countrycode)
lapply(names(lst1), function(x) write.csv(lst1[[x]], 
   file = paste0("output", x, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%        
    unite(NameRemarks, Name, Remarks, sep= " - ") %>%
    group_by(Countrycode) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Occupation, values_from = NameRemarks)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  Countrycode    rn Engineer     Veterinarian Shepherd
#        <int> <int> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>   
#1           1     1 Mark - Ok    <NA>         <NA>    
#2           1     2 Jerry - None <NA>         <NA>    
#3           2     1 <NA>         Marie - Ok   <NA>    
#4           2     2 <NA>         Nolan - Ok   <NA>    
#5           2     3 <NA>         <NA>         Max - Ok
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("Mark", "Jerry", "Marie", "Nolan", "Max"
), Occupation = c("Engineer", "Engineer", "Veterinarian", "Veterinarian", 
"Shepherd"), Countrycode = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Remarks = c("Ok", 
"None", "Ok", "Ok", "Ok")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: how to output one text per country? @akrun

Comment: I would like to use only base functions @akrun

Comment: Yes. I want to split with the Occupation but I want to create separate text files per Country.code @akrun

Comment: split(with(df1, paste(Name, Remarks, sep=" - ")), df1$Occupation) is OK but I want to create separate text files for every country. I try using write.table() @akrun

Comment: Yes, thank you! but how do I create separate output.txt using the lst1? @akrun

Comment: How about for a .txt file? @akrun

Comment: When I run the Map(capture.output....)  this error occurs:  Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : invalid 'description' argument @arkun

Comment: @KylaCelineMarcaida ssorry, need to remov e the `MoreArgs` updated it shsould work now

Comment: That's awesome! One last bit, how can I automatically remove the $, "NameRemarks", and the 1     , 2     etc. in the output.txt? @akrun

Comment: @KylaCelineMarcaida That could be done, but it needs some `paste` and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is iterate making named .csv files with `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Example data
df <- tibble(name = c('Mark', 'Jerry', 'Marie', 'Nolan', 'Max'),
             occupation = rep(c('engineer', 'vetenarian', 'shepher'), c(2, 2, 1)),
             country_code = rep(c(1, 2), c(3, 2)),
             remarks = c('ok', 'none', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok'))

# Get a list of all occupations as a vector
occupations <- df$occupation %>% unique()

# Create a list of subdataframes split by occupation
dfs <- map(occupations, ~ df %>%
      filter(occupation == paste(.x)))

# Create .csv files from your dataframe list in your 
# working directory: "engineers.csv", "veterinarians.csv", ...
walk2(dfs, occupations, ~ write_csv(.x, paste0(.y, 's.csv')))
```

Comment: I only want the Name - Remarks columns in the output @Adam B.

Comment: And the output should be a .txt file not a .csv @Adam B.

Comment: You can easily select only Name + Remarks by adding a pipe with `select()` into the `map()` call:

`dfs <- map(occupations, ~ df %>%
      filter(occupation == paste(.x)) %>% 
      select(name, remarks))`

Comment: You sure you want a .txt file? You can open a .csv file with any text editor, it will look the same like .txt if you open it in Notepad, and if you need to work with it again, you can always easily load it back into R or any other statistical software. However, if you save it as .txt, it might make it difficult to load it.

Comment: I need base R functions only. And yes, I need it in a .txt format @Adam B.

Comment: Ok then it may be best to go with @akrun's option. I don't work with base R much, sorry.